# Why is my nested while loop not working? if and second while loop is expected

Tags: python, selenium, loops, while-loop, nested-loops

the program should search for a image in the first loop and add it to a list, in the secon loop should he search till he find a image that isnt already in the list. PyCharm give me the errors that `while search = True:` `and if pic == used` is expected.

```
used = []
search = True

#First Loop
while True:
    pic = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,value=".image-post img")
    time.sleep(2)
    pic_url = pic.get_attribute("src")
    pic_title = pic.get_attribute("alt")
    used.append(pic)
    time.sleep(200)

#Second loop
        while search = True:
        pic = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=".image-post img")
        if pic == used
            search = True

        else:
            search = False

    used.append(pic)
```

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
used = []

#First Loop
while True:
    search = True #moved search = True here so that the nested loop will run each iteration of the main loop as it will be set back to True
    pic = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,value=".image-post img")
    time.sleep(2)
    pic_url = pic.get_attribute("src") #you’re not doing anything with this from the looks of it
    pic_title = pic.get_attribute("alt") #same with this
    used.append(pic)
    time.sleep(200)

#Second loop
        while search:
            pic = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=".image-post img")
            if pic != used:#may want to change “used” to “used[-1]” here as used is a list while it appears pic is not, so the -1 will get the last value in used
                search = False

    used.append(pic)
```

You could also replace search with True and change the “search = False” with “break”

Comment: Thanks, you already helped me a lot but there is still a problem with `if pic != used` even with the [-1] btw is there a option that he search for every value in used and not only the latest? he say ':' expected:336 and that is my code there. `    time.sleep(2)
    while search:
        pic = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=".image-post img")
        if pic != used[-1]
            search = False


    used.append(pic)`

Comment: sry my code in line 336 is that.  `if pic != used[-1]`

Comment: you removed the : after used which is required as it signals the end of the if statement, change it to "if pic != used[-1]:"

Answer (score 0):

I think that you used a bad operator type. By that, I mean that you should probably use **==** and not **=**.
*Check it and inform me*.

Comment: The block below the second `while` statement also needs to be indented

Comment: Yeah, didn't see that. Oops :0

Comment: I alredy used == in my code, i forget it here. sry